# Unable to supply the product pages to a separate method after crawling the nested categories

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to build a script using scrapy to parse the category links recursively and then print the links of different items in a separate method. I have been able to reach the product pages by looping recursively through the categories but can't find any way to print the product links in a separate method.

[webpage link](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/gb?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a/gben/web/main/products/subcategory_pages/Tools_P-25/3d7b966e-fe2c-4aab-ad5f-b98db236d62a)

Categories [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llLxT.jpg)

Product pages [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN2LB.jpg)

This is my current approach:

```
class mySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"

    start_urls = ['https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/gb?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a/gben/web/main/products/subcategory_pages/Tools_P-25/3d7b966e-fe2c-4aab-ad5f-b98db236d62a']
    headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36"}

    def parse(self,response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
        for item in soup.select("div:has(> h3:contains('Category')) > ul > li > a"):
            item_link = response.urljoin(item.get("href"))
            yield scrapy.Request(item_link,headers=self.headers,callback=self.parse)

    """can't find any way to pass the product pages to the following method"""
    """in order to parse product links from there"""

    def parse_content(self,response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
        for item in soup.select("[class='pxc-sales-data-wrp'][data-product-key] h3 > a[href][onclick]"):
            print(item.get_text(stript=True))
```

> How can I supply the product pages to a separate method after crawling the nested categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add conditional statement that will call another callback if url leads to product listing page.

```
def parse(self,response):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("div:has(> h3:contains('Category')) > ul > li > a"):
        item_link = response.urljoin(item.get("href"))
        if "/products/list_pages/" in item_link:
            yield scrapy.Request(item_link,headers=self.headers,callback=self.parse_content)
        else:
            yield scrapy.Request(item_link,headers=self.headers,callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/bNdD8XLF) is how I tried before you came up with this excellent suggestion. Is my linked solution up to the standard?